# How to get name and number from the contact list

Tags: iphone

How can we use get only the name and number or number from the contact list by clicking add button and it should be add in the textbox also. Can anyone help me? Please give me some code or tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Address Book API](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html&ei=AVeZTaH9PNKN0QHDq5n1Cw&usg=AFQjCNE1RzNEbaHazXJCJjapaIGe0_wS-w).